Other ways to get the weapons from Godrick’s Remembrance
So I killed Godrick recently, and obtained his remembrance.
I didn’t know what to do with it, so I just consumed it. After discovering what the alternative was, I now fully regret this decision.
Is there any way to get his remembrance again? Alternatively, is it possible to get the weapons you would have gotten from the remembrance otherwise?

You need remembrances to get boss weapons or spells, you can't get them otherwise.
Luckily, you don't have to wait for the next new game cycle to obtain it again. There are several Walking Mausoleums in game, which allow you to get a remembrance from a defeated boss again. But only once per a mausoleum, so choose wisely.

You do not need to have the remembrance prior to duplicating it? I always thought I have to wait before consuming/picking a reward from rememberance after I duplicate it so that I won't lose this possibility in the future
